# Swift 2 Date Picker

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have been messing around with date pickers for a university assignment and I came across something that is giving me trouble. Here is the layout of part of my project, which I will explain after the picture.

[image: Image of my main storyboard layout]

Basically, I have a date picker on my daily goals view controller. I want to be able to pick a date, then press the button "View Day", which will then direct me to the view controller on the right side of this picture. The view controller on the right will display goals for the day that was picked by the previous action. I can then add/delete goals for that specific day.

Now, I have looked at a few different ways of implementing this functionality. I would like to use core data to store arrays with indexes that point to specific days and goals for those days; however, I do not know how to implement this.

One idea would be for me to create an array of dates, which would point to arrays for specific dates. With these arrays for specific dates, there would be an array of goals for each specific day.

If anybody has any ideas on how to implement this functionality or any pieces of code or references that I could use, I would be very grateful!

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is quite broad, but as a starter, Core Data can't store arrays.  You need to use relations between entity types.  I would create an entity for a "Day", that has a date property and a one to many relationship to "Goal" entities.  The Goal entity would contain the name/description/status etc of the Goal.

Comment: I do agree that your question is broad, but if you want to get started with CoreData, there are a lot of tutorials on YouTube you can refer to.